# C# EmguCV Mat.Ptr

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm trying to convert C++ OpenCV code to C# Emgucv. I converted some lines but I get stucked on the one line.

```
Mat detectionMat(detection.size[2], detection.size[3], CV_32F, detection.ptr<float>());
```

I converted like above

```
 Mat detectionMat = new Mat(detection.SizeOfDimemsion[2], detection.SizeOfDimemsion[3], Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, detection.Ptr.ToPointer());
```

But I know I have a problem at **detection.Ptr.ToPointer()** I couldn't convert. Thanks in advance.

```
 caffe.PopulateNet(net);

        Mat prob;
        Mat img2 = new Mat(300,300,img.Depth,img.NumberOfChannels); 
        Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Resize(img, img2, new Size(300, 300));

        //Mat inputBlob = DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(img2,0.007843, new Size(300, 300), new MCvScalar(127.5,127.5,127.5), true); // ??
        Mat inputBlob = DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(img, 0.007843, mean: new MCvScalar(127.5, 127.5, 127.5), swapRB: false); 
        net.SetInput(inputBlob, "data");

        Mat detection = net.Forward("detection_out");
        Mat detectionMat = new Mat(detection.SizeOfDimemsion[2], detection.SizeOfDimemsion[3], Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, detection.ptr<float>()); 

        double confidenceThreshold = 0.2;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Musa, which version of Emgu CV are you using. In the latest there is no Mat constructor that takes the parameters you specify. You have a choice of:

```
Mat Constructor (Int32, Int32, DepthType, Int32)
Mat Constructor (Int32[], DepthType, IntPtr,IntPtr[])
Mat Constructor (Size, DepthType, Int32, IntPtr, Int32)
Mat Constructor (Int32, Int32, DepthType, Int32, IntPtr, Int32)
```

I am guessing that you mean to use the last one. If so this is an IntPtr to your data. But not knowing what the data is I cannot help much. It would be very helpful to know what detection is, or a complete code snippet.

EDIT:
Musa, I think I see what you are trying to do although I have not worked with the DNN part of EmguCV. You have a Mat object as a result of the net.Forward() call. I think you might try the following and see if it helps:

```
Mat detectionMat = new Mat(detection.SizeOfDimemsion[2], detection.SizeOfDimemsion[3], Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, detection.NumberOfChannels, detection.DataPointer, detection.Step);
```

Doug

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm using version the 3.3.0 EmguCV. I also will edit question with all lines of code. Thanks for attention

Comment: I will after I also inform about last stand. Thanks for your interest